# Remapping <C-j> to <Plug>delimitMateS-Tab doesn't work at all

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I use the delimitMate plugin in vim for auto-close pairs. The  is the default mapping to jump out of the pairs in insert mode. I want to remap it as:

```
imap <C-j> <Plug>delimitMateS-Tab
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Comment: What does `verbose imap <c-j>` say? Is it actually mapped to the function? Does the mapping give an error?

Comment: @FDinoff: No, it doen't. The keys are mapped to other function. Thank you.